# Hashcat Combinator 3 word attack

Tags: passwords, hashcode, hashcat, method-combination

I am able to do a two word combinator attack using Hashcat but when I try to add a third word list it does not work but no error is generated, only to use --help for assistance.  Hashcat version is 6.25
The code I use is

hashcat -m 22000 hashfile -a 1 wordlst1.txt wordlist2.txt wordlist3.txt

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this today internally to hashcat itself.

Instead, external tools like [combinator3](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hashcat_utils#combinator3) or [combinatorX](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hashcat_utils#combinatorx) (available in [hashcat-utils](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat-utils)) can be used, piping the results directly into hashcat:

`combinator3 list1.txt list2.txt list3.txt | hashcat -a 0 [...]`

But this is much slower than `-a 1`. One way to improve performance is to pipe in the first two lists combined, and then append the third list with rules that append the third word:

`combinator list1.txt list2.txt | hashcat -a 0 -r list3-append.rule [...]`

... but then the length of your third wordlist is constrained by the number of rules that your setup can load into memory (usually a few million).

Comment: What is the difference between hashcat and hashcat-utils? Also can I use hashcat-utils on Windows as I do with hashcat?

Comment: hashcat-utils is just a separate set of little standalone programs. And yes, Windows versions are included.

Comment: Would you know where to download hashcat utils for Windows? The version I downloaded  utils 1.9 does not have combinator3.

Comment: @drive That is odd - where are you downloading from? The GitHub release .7z has both combinator3.bin and combinator3.exe :
https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat-utils/releases/tag/v1.9